# add for loop results to an empty array

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop that goes through a series of data. I would like to store the result of elevations[i].elevation*3.28084; in an array. Right now it only has one value outside of the loop.

```
     var data2 = [];


     for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
        data2 = elevations[i].elevation*3.28084; // convert meters to feet        
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign to array *entries*, not to the array itself:

```
data2[i] = elevations[i].elevation*3.28084;
// --^^^
```

Alternately, use `push`:

```
data2.push(elevations[i].elevation*3.28084);
// --^^^^^^-------------------------------^
```

Comment: Or in this case, where `data2` starts empty (which my first example above also assumes), you can use `map` [as shown by dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49540136/157247).

Answer (score 3):

You want to push new items `elevation[i].elevation * 3.28084` into array. However, it's more convenient to use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var data2 = elevations.map(function (elevation) {
  return elevation.elevation * 3.28084
})
```

Comment: In this specific case, where `data2` starts empty, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

You're only assigning a value to the previously declared variable `data2`, use the function `push` instead to add new values to the array, or use the current index to add new values to that array.

```
var data2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
  data2.push(elevations[i].elevation * 3.28084); // convert meters to feet        
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to push your result to that array like this :

```
var data2 = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
        data2.push(elevations[i].elevation*3.28084); // convert meters to feet        
    }
```

Or you can insert data to that array using map :

```
    var data2 = elevations.map(function(value){
return value.elevation*3.28084;
}
```